# Максимальное количество делителей числа в интервале [ M; N ]

Tags: python, pascal

```pascal
uses crt;

function KolDel(n: longint): integer; //функция для подсчета делителей
var
    i, k: integer;
begin
    k := 1; //пока делитель 1, само число
    for i := 1 to round(sqrt(n)) do //от 1 до крня из числа(дальше нет смысла проверять)
        if n mod i = 0 then k := k + 1; //если данное число делится на очередное, прибавляем
    KolDel := k; //присваиваем значение функции
end;

var
    m, n, i: longint;
    mx: integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    repeat //вводим интервал с проверкой
        writeln('Ведите интервал вычислений n>m');
        readln(m, n);
    until n > m;
    
    mx := 1; //пока максимальное число делителей = 1
    for i := m to n do//идем по интервалу
        if KolDel(i) > mx then mx := KolDel(i); //ищем сколько максимально есть делителей у этих чисел
    writeln('Максимальное количество делителе=', mx, ' имеют:');
    
    for i := m to n do//снова идем по интервалу
        if KolDel(i) = mx then write(i, ' ');//если у числа максимальное число делителей, 
    //выводим его на экран
    readln
end.
```

```
from math import sqrt
x = int(input('M : '))
y = int(input('N : '))

def KolDel(N):
    k = 1
    N = round(sqrt(N))
    for i in N:
    if N % i=0
    k = k + 1
    KolDel(N) = k
    return k
```

Помогите перевести с Паскаля на Питон

Comment: "в интервали"....

Answer (score 1):

```
dividers = [] #список для делителей.
for divider in range(M, N):
    if divider % X == 0: #проверяем делимость
        dividers.append(divider) #добавляем делитель

print(len(dividers)) #выводим длину списка
```

ну а в общем, я не понял, что Вы подразумеваете под 'максимальное количество делителей'. он всегда одинаков в статическом диапазоне для определённого Х.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто не понял задачу, подробнее можно почитать здесь. Так же тут есть формулы для более оптимального поиска кол-ва делителей используя простые числа.

https://zaochnik.com/spravochnik/matematika/delimost/nahozhdenie-vseh-delitelej-chisla/

Ваша функция `KolDel` работает не верно. Я переписала алгоритм, который работает верно, но он не оптимален. В качестве проверки можно использовать число 60 - имеет 12 делителей.

```py
import math

def countDividers(n):
    if n <= 0: return 0 # условно будем так считать
    if n == 1: return 1

    k = 2 # делителей изначально 2, само число и единица.
    for i in range(2, round(math.sqrt(n)) + 1): 
        if n % i == 0:
            k += 1 if i == n // i else 2 #считаем и делитель и частное, если они не совпадают
    return k

def maxDividersCountAtRange(m , n):
    if m > n : m, n = n, m # меняем местами если m > n, только для учебных програм

    maxDivs = 0 #
    numberWithMaxDivs = [] #список чисел с максимальным числом делителей
    for i in range(m, n): #идем по интервалу
        d = countDividers(i) #записываем результат в переменную для оптимизации
        if d > maxDivs: #ищем максимум
            maxDivs = d
            numberWithMaxDivs = [] #очищаем список при изменении максимума
        if d == maxDivs:
            numberWithMaxDivs.append(i) #добавляем число в список

    return maxDivs, numberWithMaxDivs

print(maxDividersCountAtRange(20,80))
```

Ввод и красивый вывод можно дописать самостоятельно

Питон знаю мало, так что правки приветствуются